# TypeError: doc2bow expects an array of unicode tokens on input, not a single string

Tags: python, nlp

```
import re
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize ,word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import  stopwords
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
from collections import Counter


 article1 = """Indian landscape is rich and replete with art, but not all of it gets a platform to be exhibited. With the upcoming edition of Hindustan Times Imagine Fest 2019, arts from across India will get a chance to become visible to people, who can also buy these artworks since the concept of this festival is to have all artworks priced below ₹2,00,000. """
 word = word_tokenize(article1)
 islower = [t.lower() for t in word if t.isalpha()]
 dictionary = Dictionary(islower)
 computer_id = dictionary.token2id.get("computer")
 corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(article) for article in article1]
 print(corpus[4][:10])
```

> I used all libraries but I cant understand whats the problem, A little guidance would be
>   appreciated.

Comment: Actually, the above error is because when a dictionary is used we need data like  'List of List'.[['Hello','Hai'],['How','are','you'],['how','is','your','day']] Finally solved. Thank you.